# Derivation of Lorentz Contraction WITHOUT light roundtrip

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, relativity, time-dilation

A typical Lorentz Contraction proof relies on the axiom that "the speed of light is constant" and goes as follows. Given:

- Frame $F_1$ moves at speed $v$ relative to frame $F_0$. In frame $F_1$ sit 2 parallel mirrors.
- Distance between mirrors is measured as $l_0$ in $F_1$ (at rest relative to mirrors).
- Distance between mirrors is measured as $l$ in $F_0$ (while mirrors move past in $F_1$ at speed $v$).
- Time for light to make "roundtrip" between mirrors measured as $t_0$ in $F_1$ (at rest relative to mirrors).
- Time for light to make "roundtrip" between mirrors measured as $t$ in $F_0$ (while mirrors move past in $F_1$ at speed $v$).
- Already proved $t = \frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=\gamma t_0$ (time dilation).

A "roundtrip" of light passing between mirrors takes two trips; measured from $F_0$, those trips take times $t_1$ and $t_2$. During those trips, the ship travels $vt_1$ and $vt_2$, meaning light travels $l+vt_1$ and $l-vt_2$ when light moves in the same and opposite directions as $F_1$, respectively, all measured in $F_0$. The constancy of the speed of light gives:

- Trip 1 (light moves same direction as $F_1$ relative to $F_0$): $c = \frac{l + vt_1}{t_1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $t_1 = \frac{l}{c-v}$
- Trip 2 (light moves opposite direction as $F_1$ relative to $F_0$): $c = \frac{l - vt_2}{t_2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $t_2 = \frac{l}{c+v}$
- So, $\color{red}{t = t_1 + t_2 = \frac{l}{c-v} + \frac{l}{c+v} =\frac{2lc}{c^2-v^2}= \frac{2l/c}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} = \frac{2\gamma^2}{c} l}$.

Measured in $F_1$, the "roundtrip" distance is simply $2l_0$, and so $c=\frac{2l_0}{t_0} \Rightarrow t_0 = \frac{2l_0}{c}$.

Combining this with time dilation yields $t=\gamma t_0 = \gamma\frac{2l_0}{c} = \frac{2\gamma}{c}l_0$.

Putting it all together yields $$\frac{2\gamma^2}{c}l =t = \frac{2\gamma}{c}l_0 \Rightarrow l = \frac{l_0}{\gamma} \tag*{$\Box$}$$

## Question:

Can I shorten this proof to just use "one trip" between the mirrors instead of a "round trip"? I have tried, and cannot! I $\color{red}{\text{have highlighted in red}}$ the part of the proof where the round trip yields some nice cancellation.

What am I missing?

- There are proofs that rely on axioms other than "the speed of light is constant", but I'm looking for a proof that just relies on that.
- The typical proof for time dilation $t=\frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ involves light bouncing between two mirrors that are PERPENDICULAR to the motion of the reference frames. I went through this proof, and it absolutely does NOT break down when only one trip between the mirrors is considered. The proof in this question involves mirrors separated by a distance PARALLEL to the motion of the reference frames.
- If "roundtrip" is unclear, here are two animations, each depicting two "roundtrips":

[image: Roundtrips with tracers]

> [image: 2 roundtrips]

First image made by me. Second image from [Help Me Gain an Intuitive Understanding of Lorentz Contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14362/help-me-gain-an-intuitive-understanding-of-lorentz-contraction?newreg=e8de486676b74a75848892c2f4a06003) , which goes through this same proof based on the speed of light being constant.

> A proof I’ve seen for time dilation is as follows, and only seems to require a single trip of a light beam:
>
> Suppose a pair of mirrors separated by distance $L$ is moving past at speed $v$, such that the displacement between the mirrors is perpendicular to the motion of the mirrors. In the reference frame of the mirrors, light bouncing between the mirrors travels distance $L$ in $t_0$ seconds at speed $c=\frac{L}{t_0}$. In the reference frame relative to which the mirrors are moving at speed $v$, however, light bouncing between the mirrors takes time $t$ to do so and travels $\sqrt{(vt)^2 + L^2}$. So, $c = \frac{\sqrt{(vt)^2 + L^2}}{t}$ as well because the speed of light is constant to all observers. Solving for $t$ and substituting $t_0=\frac{L}{c}$ yields $t=\frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$.
>
> [image: light bouncing between mirrors separated by L]
>
> Image used is from [what about doing the laser beam in a moving reference frame but with a ball](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122201/what-about-doing-the-laser-beam-in-a-moving-reference-frame-but-with-a-ball)

Comment: Hey Zach, in order to comply with our [referencing guidelines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) you should really quote that image and indicate [its source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14383/124). If it's not clear how to do that, feel free to ask for help. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the inability of measuring the [one-way speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light).

Comment: A derivation of the Lorentz transformation doesn't have to talk about light at all. See, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0302045

Comment: Zach, I note that your edit doesn't change the fact that you have an unattributed image. That still needs to be fixed.

Comment: @DavidZ spent some time making a similar gif in Mathematica (the red/blue one made by ME), but I actually like having them both here. In the Markdown I posted the link to the phsyics.stackexchange post from which I copied the other image.

Comment: Hey @BenCrowell that paper relies on the "homogeneity of space", which may be a good way to answer this (convince me!), but I suppose I'm looking for a derivation that relies on the *constancy of the speed of light*, which is a pretty basic, SE (not GE) axiom. I'd love to just tweak this proof a bit but it doesn't seem to be working, and it makes me wonder whether this proof only works for a convenient but not-quite-correct reason. Does that make sense?

Comment: The image you reused needs to be quoted (using `>` at the beginning of the line) and identified as having come from that other post, though. It's not enough to just make the image a link to the other post; you need to include some text like "from [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14383/124)" to make it clear where it came from even for people who aren't hovering their mice over it.

Comment: @MarkH INCREDIBLE - could that actually be the reason? Does this proof style simply not work for a one-way transit? This is SUCH a commonly-taught proof, and I'm starting to feel like it relies on Einstein's assumption mentioned in that Wiki ("light travels the same speed in both directions") in a complicated way. Can you help me understand what's going on?

Comment: @BenCrowell I meant "SR (not GR)" as in the assumption is just related to Special Relativity not General Relativity. (being on StackExchange, I typo'ed it as "SE")

Comment: Oh, this is an entirely separate matter from voting. Anyway, it wasn't done quite right, but I went ahead and just fixed it.

Comment: @DavidZ thank you for the assistance adhering to the guidelines, next time I’ll be sure to read them carefully before posting!

Comment: Although you state that you can use "only one trip" using the perpendicular method, I don't believe that is possible.  You have a beam going and returning in the forward direction, and another beam going and returning in the perpendicular direction?  Maybe I am not understanding you.

Comment: @Guill I edited the question to be more clear about the proof of time dilation seeming to only need one trip of a light beam.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with one trip, but it's a bit trickier to identify what's happening. Ultimately it amounts to effectively using Lorentz transformations, albeit in a more physical way in terms of the functioning of clocks in SR.

Consider one way trip from left to right mirror.

Let's note:

1. Frame $F_0$ will claim it takes time $l/(c-v)$ between the two events.
2. Frame $F_1$ will claim it takes time $l_0/c$.

#### Reconciliation

Frame $F_0$ will insist that the clocks of $F_1$ are unsynchronized, with the one on the left leading the one on the right by an amount $\frac{v l_0}{c^2}$. Plus, moving clocks of $F_1$ are all running slow by a factor of $\gamma$ (you can find this in any basic book on SR $-$ eg. Resnick-Halliday-Krane or Resnick's book on SR).

**$F_0$ will mumble to himself:** Hmm! Silly guy, $F_1$ $-$ used two different clocks to measure the time elapsed between two events, but forgot to sync his clocks! That's why the time elapsed for $F_1$ wasn't $l_0/c$, but rather $l_0/c + vl_0/c^2$. Plus, these moving clocks of $F_1$ were all running slow by a factor of $\gamma$. So, the "actual time elapsed" between the two events was $\gamma\big(\frac{l_0}{c}+\frac{v l_0}{c^2} \big)$. And, of course, being the meticulous observer that I'm (who has all his clocks synced), this is what I measure. So $F_0$ will conclude,

$$ \frac{l}{c-v} = \gamma\bigg(\frac{l_0}{c}+\frac{v l_0}{c^2} \bigg). $$

Which leads to,

$$ l = \frac{l_0}{\gamma}.$$

---

So, what's up with a round trip? We can now understand that when you let the light do a round trip, $F_0$ cannot argue that two different (unsynchronized) clocks were used by $F_1$ in his measurement (because only one clock, sitting at, say, the left mirror, records both the events). The only grudge $F_0$ can now have is that the single clock used by $F_1$ was running slow by a factor of $\gamma$.

*The great thing about relativity is that all observers have these grudges for one another $-$ and they can "fix" space & time measurements of another observer by noting when & where the events took place, & hence perpetually be under the delusion that they all measured space & time the right way! :-)*

---

A very nice book which has amazing thought experiments in SR is the book by N. D. Mermin. In this book, he basically explores SR through light signals & doppler shifts, and I recommend it for the sheer joy it brings to the mind through numerous insights & the way it molds the intuition of a person used to non-relativistic mechanics.

Comment: How did you come with the $vl_0/c^2$? If these considerations hold when the ligth does just one trip, then why one can derive the right expressions when the mirrors are perpendicular to the motion of the frames without checking the synchronization of the clocks?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the time dilation result you can use the fact that both static and moving observers agree on the relative speed of motion (by symmetry) to get the reciprocal factor for length contraction.